# Sqltabledependency stops working suddenly

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldependency

I have created sqltable dependency and it works fine for onchange and onerror events just for few mins. All the changes gets notified for just few mins and this time is not constant all the time. Sometime it takes 5 mins/10 mins /some random number. It gives me the message that "TableDependency stopped working" and after that no events gets notified. So the question is, what could be the issue? or anyone faced same issue earlier? Just for info, i have the owner level permissions on db i am using. Thanks in advance and let me know if any more info is required

Comment: `It gives me the message that "TableDependency stopped working"` Please show us a screenshot of that message.

Comment: Add the code to your question. I believe the "TableDependency stopped working" message is generated by the application code. If there is a problem with the depenedency, the SqlNotificationEventArgs of the OnChange event will contain more information to help identify the cause.